# What is תַרְדֵּמַת מַרְמִיטָה?

Tags: words, midrash

Following on from my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118121/22152)

What is the third type of תרדמה - i.e. "תַרְדֵּמַת מַרְמִיטָה", that the Midrash in [Bereishis Rabbah 17:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.17.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is explaining:

> רַב אָמַר שָׁלשׁ תַּרְדֵמוֹת הֵן, תַּרְדֵּמַת שֵׁנָה, וְתַרְדֵּמַת נְבוּאָה, **וְתַרְדֵּמַת מַרְמִיטָה**. תַּרְדֵּמַת שֵׁנָה וַיַּפֵּל ה' אֱלֹהִים תַּרְדֵּמָה עַל הָאָדָם וַיִּישָׁן. תַּרְדֵּמַת נְבוּאָה (בראשית טו, יב): וַיְהִי הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ לָבוֹא וְתַרְדֵּמָה נָפְלָה עַל אַבְרָם. **תַּרְדֵּמַת מַרְמִיטָה** (שמואל א כו, יב): אֵין רֹאֶה וְאֵין יוֹדֵעַ וְאֵין מֵקִיץ כִּי כֻלָּם יְשֵׁנִים כִּי תַּרְדֵּמַת ה' נָפְלָה עֲלֵיהֶם. רַבָּנָן אָמְרֵי אַף תַּרְדֵּמָה שֶׁל שְׁטוּת, דִּכְתִיב (ישעיה כט, י): כִּי נָסַךְ עֲלֵיכֶם ה' רוּחַ תַּרְדֵּמָה.
>
> *Rav said that there are three types of 'tardeima' and they are: 1) A 'tardeima' of deep sleep, 2) A 'tardeima' of prophecy, and 3) A 'tardeima' of ________(?).*
>
> *A 'tardeima' of sleep - e.g. ([Bereishis 2:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "So the LORD G-d cast a deep sleep upon the man; and he slept". 'Tardeima' of prophecy - e.g. ([Bereishis 15:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.15.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "As the sun was about to set, a deep sleep fell upon Abram". A 'tardeima' of ____? - e.g. ([Shmuel I 26:12](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.26.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "No one saw or knew or woke up; all remained asleep; a deep sleep from the LORD had fallen upon them.

In modern Hebrew, the word "מַרְמִיטָה" means a groundhog i.e. a member of the rodent family, perhaps best known by the 'holiday' - Groundhog Day e.g. [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94.).

The only connection I can imagine is that these animals hibernate for such a long time (apparently [3-5 months](https://animals.mom.com/groundhog-hibernation-3613.html)) they are in a state of complete disconnect from the world, which would seem to tally with the quote from Shmuel brought in the Midrash - *"No one saw or knew or woke up; all remained asleep"*. But if that is the case, how is it different to the first tardeima example that Adam experienced which is also regarded as a deep sleep? If it is a third category, it should in theory be different to the other two?

Comment: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=9JvlSI2UGRoC&pg=PA1005&dq=%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%AA+%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%98%D6%B8%D7%94&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS9_eL8tPsAhUQILcAHQw9AUg4ChDoATAFegQICBAC#v=onepage&q=%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%98%D6%B8%D7%94&f=false seems to agree that *marmita* is (approximately) the animal you refer to.

Comment: Ok @GRAPKE - so how does it differ from the first type of tardeima?

Comment: Sleep is part of daily living, hibernation is not.

Comment: So is the third category an all-encompassing sleep with a complete disconnect from the world, whereas the first is only a deep sleep? (I believe the mefarshim say that in Adam's case it was induced so that he would not feel the pain of Hashem extracting the צלע - i.e. a glorified anaesthetic.)

Comment: The third category sounds like the slumber of the bewitched in Sleeping Beauty.

Comment: Lol fairy-tale inspired

Comment: Fairy tales incorporate many themes from medrashim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Aruch ([מרמטא](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11828&st=&pgnum=226&hilite=)) says it's "like a stone", similar to *marmor* in Latin and *mármaro* in Greek, according to the "א-ב" note addition in my printed version of the Aruch.

I.e. Stonelike. *Sleeping like a stone.*

The [Maharzu](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Perush_Maharzu_on_Bereshit_Rabbah.17.5.4?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah,_Vilna,_1878&qh=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90) says it's from the word *mortem* in Latin. 
I.e. Deathlike: *Sleeping as if he was dead.*

Comment: +1 - Amazing finds! And so how would you view the difference between this tardeima and the one by Adam which comes under the first category?

Comment: @Dov -it would seem that if somebody had tried hard enough to awaken Adam during the "surgery" he would have awoken. As opposed to those who are dead-like; nothing in the world would wake them up.

Comment: i hear - good nafka minah thank you!